# Installing CPAN modules without root

Tags: perl, cpan

I followed this [helpful tutorial](http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~pbrandao/aulas/0203/AR/modules_inst_cpan.html) to get Perl installed just for my user. I am sorry to link to an external site but I think reading this is the only way to understand how to answer the question.

Anywho, I am feeding defaults to the CPAN config - the `.cpan` and `CPAN` directories created via the tutorial - yet for some reason CPAN still wants to dig into `/usr/lib/` - which it just can't get to - when I try to install a module. This was while installing `DBD::CSV`.

Here is the error message:

```
All tests successful (7 subtests UNEXPECTEDLY SUCCEEDED), 3 tests skipped.
Files=23, Tests=706,  3 wallclock secs ( 2.28 cusr +  0.54 csys =  2.82 CPU)
/usr/bin/make test -- OK
Running make install
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
ERROR: Can't create '/perl5lib/lib/Bundle/DBD'
mkdir /perl5lib: Permission denied at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/ExtUtils/Install.pm line 457
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
at -e line 1
make: *** [pure_site_install] Error 13
/usr/bin/make install  -- NOT OK
```

It seems to be going to the wrong `perl5lib`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, local::lib helps.  I suggest using cpanm instead of cpan.  I think it defaults to installing everything ~/perl5/lib/perl5.  Here's a [super useful tutorial](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/wiki/Dreamhost).

Comment: Hello - thanks for the response. I went about trying to install cpanm and it requires access to folders I am restricted from. I'll continue on with the bootstrap install of local::lib, I spose. But I wonder, is there a way to change an env. variable with regular cpan such that it won't look in usr/lib?

Comment: yeah, the environment variable **PERL5LIB** is what you want.

Answer (score 5):

[local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?local%3a%3alib) causes installers to use INSTALL_BASE, which I consider broken. I use [perlbrew](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlbrew) to install a local copy of Perl instead.

- You don't mess with your system's install of Perl, so you don't break your operating environment.
- Allows you to have multiple versions and builds of Perl installed with no hassle.
- INSTALL_BASE need not be used.
- No need for special permissions.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at this module: [local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/~apeiron/local-lib-1.008004/lib/local/lib.pm)

Answer (score 0):

did you configure the myconfig.pm inside cpan instead of letting it automatically fill in all the defaults?  During the cpan configuration you needed to add PREFIX="" for the Makefile.PL portion so that it installs the modules to this new location where you have write access.  Since its already configured automatically for you, go into .cpan/CPAN/, look for a MyConfig.pm and edit it.  locate the line "makepl_arg" and change the value in [ ] to contain PREFIX="".  Then try the perl -MCPAN -e shell and install a module.